# Java: Regular Expression for FTP server list?

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client, ftp-server

I'm writing FTP client handler in Java and I can't use FTP libraries like Apache.

My problem is that I receive the list from the server in this format:

```
drw-rw-rw- 1 ftp ftp                0 Mar 17 06:10 Tor Browser
-rw-rw-rw- 1 ftp ftp          1538814 Jun 26 00:23 setup.exe
-rw-rw-rw- 1 ftp ftp           142570 May 24 05:28 satellite A665-S6086.pdf
```

While all I need is the file/directory name and size.

Please suggest me a way to reduce the list to names and sizes, keeping in mind spacing differences between the columns and spacing in the filenames.

Thank you all in advance :)

Comment: Why do you undo all my edits? I tried to make it more readable.

Comment: Sorry, I was actually editing my post after posting it so there might be some conflict but I still can see your edits.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you just want to grab the data, you can use this regex:

```
"(?m)^.{20}\\s*(\\d+).{14}(.*)$"
```

And construct a `Pattern`, and obtain a `Matcher` corresponding to the input string and start extracting matches. The size can be obtained in `group(1)` and the file name can be obtained in `group(2)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) for fast response and accurate answer

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
    Pattern sizeAndNamePattern = Pattern.compile(
            "^-.*?(\\d+) \\w{3} \\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2} (.*)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);

    for (Matcher matcher = sizeAndNamePattern.matcher(dirListing); matcher.find();) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + " " + matcher.group(2));
    }
```

If you also want to see directories, than remove the first "-" in the pattern. If performance is an issue, you should consider a more selective pattern that avoids the .*? at the beginning.